# How to print table from wikipedia

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape Wikipedia site as a small task to learn about webscraping. The link which I'm trying to scrape is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_in_2000

I want to scrape the list of the countries according to their population which is available in the Wikipedia link. I have checked out the HTML tags and the table is available in class = wikitable. But when I run my code it is printing the result of other table which is available on the right side of the wikitable by the class name of wikitable float right. Can anyone help me in trying to figure out where I am going wrong?

```
import requests
website_url = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_in_2000').text

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')

My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable'})

links = My_table.findAll('a')
Countries = []
for link in links:
    Countries.append(link.get('title'))
    
print(Countries)
```

Comment: You should read [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/228969/python-web-scraper-to-download-table-of-transistor-counts-from-wikipedia/).

Comment: Don't scrape Wikipedia, but use the API instead! [Click here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page) for the documentation!

Comment: You have more than one object with that class. Use `findall` instead of `find`

Comment: There are two `wikitable`s on the page. The first one is the `Historical Demographics` table on the right. Since `find()` returns the first match, that's the one you're scraping.

Comment: @Barmar now I'm getting following error:

links = My_table.findAll('a')
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1578, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() 
when you meant to call find()?

Comment: You need a loop: `for table in My_table: links = table.findAll('a') ...`

Comment: Or just index it as in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tables (on that wiki page) with the same class name! Your results are coming from the first table which you don't need. Your code is correct, you just need to use `findAll()` tables and select the second one. For example

```py
[nav] In [1]: import requests
         ...: website_url = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_in_2000').text
         ...:
         ...: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
         ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url, 'html.parser')
         ...:
         ...: My_table = soup.findAll('table',{'class':'wikitable'})
         ...: My_table = My_table[1]
         ...:
         ...: links = My_table.findAll('a')
         ...: Countries = []
         ...: for link in links:
         ...:     Countries.append(link.get('title'))
         ...:
         ...: print(Countries)
['World', 'China', 'India', None, 'United States', 'Indonesia', 'Brazil', 'Russia', 'Pakistan', 'Bangladesh', 'Japan', 'Nigeria', 'Mexico', 'Germany', 'Vietnam', 'Philippines', 'Ethiopia', 'Egypt', 'Turkey', 'Iran', 'Thailand', 'France', 'United Kingdom', 'Italy', 'Democratic Republic of the Congo', 'Myanmar', 'Ukraine', None, 'South Korea', 'South Africa', 'Colombia', 'Spain', 'Argentina', 'Poland', 'Tanzania', 'Sudan', 'Kenya', 'Algeria', 'Canada', 'Morocco', 'Afghanistan', 'Uganda', 'Iraq', "Ba'athist Iraq", 'Peru', 'Nepal', 'Kingdom of Nepal', 'Venezuela', 'Uzbekistan', 'Malaysia', 'Saudi Arabia', 'North Korea', 'Taiwan', 'Ghana', 'Romania', 'Australia', 'Yemen', 'Sri Lanka', 'Syria', 'Mozambique', 'Madagascar', None, 'Ivory Coast', 'Cameroon', 'Netherlands', 'Chile', 'Angola', 'Kazakhstan', 'Cambodia', 'Niger', 'Mali', 'Ecuador', 'Burkina Faso', 'Zimbabwe', 'Guatemala', 'Malawi', 'Zambia', 'Senegal', 'Cuba', 'Greece', 'Belgium', 'Portugal', 'Czech Republic', 'Tunisia', 'Hungary', 'Federal Republic of Yugoslavia', None, 'Chad', 'Belarus', 'Guinea', 'Bolivia', 'Sweden', 'Rwanda', 'Dominican Republic', 'Haiti', 'Benin', 'Azerbaijan', 'Somalia', 'Austria', 'Bulgaria', 'Burundi', 'Switzerland', 'Honduras', 'Hong Kong', "People's Republic of China", 'El Salvador', 'Israel', 'Tajikistan', 'Paraguay', 'Togo', 'Laos', 'Papua New Guinea', 'Libya', 'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya', 'Jordan', 'Sierra Leone', 'Nicaragua', 'Denmark', 'Slovakia', 'Kyrgyzstan', 'Finland', None, 'Turkmenistan', 'Norway', None, 'Croatia', 'United Arab Emirates', 'Georgia (country)', 'Eritrea', 'Costa Rica', 'Singapore', 'Moldova', 'Republic of Ireland', 'Central African Republic', 'New Zealand', 'Republic of the Congo', 'Puerto Rico', 'Unincorporated territory', 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'Palestinian National Authority', 'Lebanon', 'Uruguay', 'Lithuania', 'Liberia', 'Panama', 'Albania', 'Mauritania', 'Armenia', 'Kuwait', 'Jamaica', 'Mongolia', 'Oman', 'Latvia', 'Bhutan', None, 'Republic of Macedonia', 'Namibia', 'Slovenia', 'Lesotho', 'Botswana', 'Guinea-Bissau', 'The Gambia', 'Gabon', 'Estonia', 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'Mauritius', None, 'Eswatini', 'United Nations', 'United Nations Transitional Administration in East Timor', 'Fiji', 'Cyprus', None, 'Qatar', 'Comoros', None, 'Djibouti', 'Réunion', 'French overseas territory', 'Guyana', 'Bahrain', 'Montenegro', 'Republic of Montenegro (1992–2006)', None, 'Cape Verde', 'Equatorial Guinea', 'Solomon Islands', 'Luxembourg', 'Macau', "People's Republic of China", 'Suriname', 'Guadeloupe', 'French overseas territories', 'Malta', 'Martinique', 'French overseas territories', 'Brunei', 'Western Sahara', 'Maldives', 'The Bahamas', 'Iceland', 'Belize', 'Barbados', 'France', 'French Polynesia', 'French overseas territories', 'New Caledonia', 'French overseas territories', 'Vanuatu', 'French Guiana', 'French overseas territories', 'Samoa', 'Netherlands Antilles', 'Kingdom of the Netherlands', 'Guam', 'Unincorporated territory', 'Saint Lucia', 'São Tomé and Príncipe', 'Channel Islands', 'Crown dependency', None, 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', 'United States Virgin Islands', 'Unincorporated territory', 'Federated States of Micronesia', 'Grenada', 'Tonga', 'Aruba', 'Kingdom of the Netherlands', 'Kiribati', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Unincorporated territory', 'Seychelles', 'Dominica', 'Isle of Man', 'Crown dependency', 'Andorra', 'American Samoa', 'Unincorporated territory', 'Bermuda', 'British overseas territory', 'Marshall Islands', 'Greenland', 'Denmark', 'Faroe Islands', 'Denmark', 'Cayman Islands', 'British overseas territory', 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'Monaco', 'Liechtenstein', 'San Marino', 'Gibraltar', 'British overseas territory', 'Turks and Caicos Islands', 'British overseas territory', 'British Virgin Islands', 'British overseas territory', 'Palau', 'Cook Islands', 'New Zealand', 'Wallis and Futuna', 'French overseas territory', 'Nauru', 'Anguilla', 'British overseas territory', 'Tuvalu', 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon', 'French overseas territory', 'Saint Helena', 'British overseas territory', None, 'Montserrat', 'British overseas territory', 'Falkland Islands', 'British overseas territory', 'Niue', 'New Zealand', 'Tokelau', 'Realm of New Zealand', 'Vatican City', 'Pitcairn Islands', 'British overseas territory']
```

Comment: No need for a loop since it's just two tables and we know we need the second one! we just choose it `My_table = My_table[1]`